# Google drive api Error Code="403 Rate limit exceeded"

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

i'm using google drive api in my app. For upload and download files. When i try to upload files with different computers at same time. i'm getting this error.

```
    public static IAuthenticator CreateAuthenticator()
        {
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
            provider.ClientIdentifier = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
            provider.ClientSecret = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
            return new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
    }

    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient client)
    {
        string scope = DriveService.Scopes.Drive.ToString();

        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(scope.Split(new[] { ' ' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) { RefreshToken = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_myRefresh };
        if (state != null)
        {
            client.RefreshToken(state);
            return state;
        }
        return null;
    }

public static void CreateService(ref DriveService Serv)
        {
            string CLIENT_ID = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
            string CLIENT_SECRET = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
            string SCOPE = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
            string REDIRECT_URI = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI;
            string myToken = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_myToken;
            string myRefresh = CASNameScrollGeneral.GOOGLE_myRefresh;

          /*  parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
            parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
            parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
            parameters.Scope = SCOPE;
            parameters.AccessToken = myToken;
            parameters.RefreshToken = myRefresh;
            string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
            */

            //parameters.AccessCode = myRefresh;
            //OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
            //string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;

            Serv = new DriveService(CreateAuthenticator());
        }
```

This is my service codes. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how quickly you are inserting/updating, you might be hitting this [403 rate limit after only 1 insert per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529524/403-rate-limit-after-only-1-insert-per-second)