# How to figure out reason for rate limit errors on Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am getting User Rate Limit errors for Google Drive APIs. I am using a Service account and the limit is set to the default which is 1000 requests over 100 seconds. The maximum number of requests I am making is about 400 in a day. Still getting the rate limit errors. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557355/user-rate-limit-exceeded-after-a-few-requests/42562397#42562397

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it.