# I am Face two Issues using google Drive api : socket time out exception and user limit exceed

Tags: android-studio, google-drive-api

i face issues while connecting upload Picture to Google Drive . Sockect Time Out

my Intern was Good.
[This was my Code to upload receipt in Google Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5qeB.png)

[This Sockect Time out Exeception Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ODD.png)

In have Increased time out session. For Connect the Google drive

```
 private HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
    return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
            httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(4 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
            httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
        }
    };
}
```

Google Drive ---->Connected--> Return Code

```
   private void handleSignInResult(Intent result) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
            .addOnSuccessListener(googleAccount -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "Signed in as " + googleAccount.getEmail());
                // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                edit.putString("GoogleDriveID", "" + googleAccount.getEmail());
                edit.commit();
                googleSignInAccount=googleAccount;
                accountName=googleAccount.getEmail();

                GoogleAccountCredential      credential =
                        GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
                credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());

                Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder( AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new GsonFactory(), setHttpTimeout(credential)).setApplicationName("nnnnn")
                        .build();

                service=googleDriveService;
```

2.second I was Getting "User Limit Exceed "

```
  ERR-00006-Google Drive upload|StackTrace: GLOBAL::saveFileToDrive::IOException 
  com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 
  403 Forbidden { "code": 403, "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "message": "User Rate 
  Limit Exceeded. 
  Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota. 
  You may consider re-evaluating expected per-user traffic to the API and adjust project 
  quota limits accordingly.
  You may monitor aggregate quota usage and adjust limits in the 
  API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas? 
  project=344828444511",
  "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded", "extendedHelp": 
  "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas? 
   project=************" } ], 
  "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project 
 quota.
You may consider re-evaluating expected per-user traffic to the API and adjust project 
quota limits accordingly.
You may monitor aggregate quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: 
 https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas? 
 project=************" }
```

Increased quotes Limit in Google Developer Console . but still this Error.

Comment: The error message says your quote was exceeded. Can you verify that?

Comment: yes quotes limit as 100

Comment: And how many calls did you make?

Comment: per user, 50 call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Rate Limit Exceeded with google drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652829/user-rate-limit-exceeded-with-google-drive-api)

Comment: NO. Aldready refered link. the User using newly. before .he does not used Google Back up of my Project.